# js Drop Down Menu Not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I dont know why is this not working ? I am trying to make a drop down menu and when I hovering over in the page it work but if i hovered in the linke it dosn't work In short, this drop-down list does the opposite
i need fix or a better way for this drop down menu

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ddxa2.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4Wvn.png)

**Html**

```
<body>
    <div class="wrap">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top navbarcolor  ">
            <div class="container ">
                <div class="navbar-header active">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand Brand-Color active " href="#">MediQ.ch</a>
                </div>
                <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">

                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><a class="navbar-R-C  " href="#">AdminStraion</a>
                        </li>

                        <li class="dropdown  sub-menu-parent">
                            <a id="drop" href="#" class="navbar-R-C nav-link dropdown-toggle " data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">BookMarker
                  <span class="caret"></span></a>

                            <ul id="content" class="dropdown-menu " role="menu">
                                <li><a class="content " href="#">ACETILXSUBSTANCE2</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a class="content " href="#">HIDROCORTIZOLXBENZTIL</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a class="content " href="#">SUBSTANCE3XSUBSTANCE4</a>
                                </li>

                            </ul>
                        </li>

                        <li><a class="navbar-R-C " href="#">Contact</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>

                </div>
                <!--/.nav-collapse -->
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>



</body>
```

**Css**

```
.navbar-R-C:hover {
    color: white !important;
}
.content {
    color: White !important;
}
.dropdown-menu {
    min-width: 250px;
    max-width: 250px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #3E606F;
    margin-top: -6px !important;
    color: white !important;
    border-radius: 15px !important;
}
.dropdown-menu > li > a:hover {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #EC407A;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-left: 7px !important;
    margin-right: 7px !important;
    display: inline-block;
    color: White;
    border-radius: 10px !important;
}
.dropdown-menu:after {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 210px;
    top: -6px;
    left: -30px;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 10px solid #3E606F;
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
    content: '';
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.wrap nav ul li').hover(function() {
        // Toggles slide but stops if not hover anymore
        $(this).find('ul').stop().slideToggle();
        // Toggles on and of the active class (triangle)
        $(this).find('div').toggleClass('active');
    }
    );
}
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this. it contains your code but some css are override by bootstrap css so you have to override bootstrap css to look like what you want. and the new thing is bootstrap.css, bootstrap.js and jquery.js dont forget to include these file here it loads directly from web you can download and link these file for offline use.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top navbarcolor  ">
        <div class="container ">
            <div class="navbar-header active">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand Brand-Color active " href="#">MediQ.ch</a>
            </div>
            <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a class="navbar-R-C  " href="#">AdminStraion</a>
                    </li>

                    <li class="dropdown  sub-menu-parent">
                        <a id="drop" href="#" class="navbar-R-C nav-link dropdown-toggle " data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">BookMarker
              <span class="caret"></span></a>

                        <ul id="content" class="dropdown-menu " role="menu">
                            <li><a class="content " href="#">ACETILXSUBSTANCE2</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a class="content " href="#">HIDROCORTIZOLXBENZTIL</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a class="content " href="#">SUBSTANCE3XSUBSTANCE4</a>
                            </li>

                        </ul>
                    </li>

                    <li><a class="navbar-R-C " href="#">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>

            </div>
            <!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div>
    </nav>  
    <div class="container">
      <h3>Navbar With Dropdown</h3>
      <p>This example adds a dropdown menu for the "Page 1" button in the navigation bar.</p>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you gave me example for bootstrab  droopdown  but with hover effect plz

Comment: what exactly you want to do when hovering can you please explain so that i can help and what exactly you want to hover

Comment: i need somthing like that https://codepen.io/gjermundnor/pen/KwpRbV?q=jquery%20drop%20down%20menu&limit=all&order=popularity&depth=everything&show_forks=false

Comment: it this code is working it may be the issue of jquery version please try with different jquery version

Comment: ok Thanks but can you gave my bootstrap example that look like

Comment: i think the problem is in your jquery version try using another version with same code